# What are most recommended 360-degree Video Players for Web?

Tags: web, cross-browser, video-streaming, virtual-reality, webvr

I am working on new Website for playing 360-degree videos on both Desktop & Mobile web browsers, and was looking for the most recommended 360-degree/WebVR players that can play Live/Playback videos and can support HLS streaming protocol.

Answer (score 0):

DeoVR is the best one and free.

Users have an option to switch between WebVR and native app

https://deovr.com/doc/webvr